# Glib 2.0.0 cross compilation for android

Tags: glib

glib cross compilation for android -Getting configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling error

I have tried to compile glib for android target using ./configure --host=aarch64-linux-android but it is failed

Comment: What version of GLib are you trying to build? From the fact that you’re calling `configure`, it looks like it’s an autotools version of GLib. Those versions are now very old and completely unsupported upstream. They contain unfixed security vulnerabilities.

You will want to try building a more up to date version of GLib, using Meson. Meson has better support for cross-compilation. See https://mesonbuild.com/Cross-compilation.html

Comment: glib 2.0.0 is more than 20 years old.  It predates the existence of Android by 5+ years.